# Embed multiple Data attribute to div via FOR loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Want to embed data attributes in a DIV DOM like below.

1. Dropdown menu `<a>` data-key and data-endpoint values are rendering through JSON response.
2. Have to get each `<a>` data-endpoint-key and value using FOR loop.
3. Embed in id="form-component" using jQuery script and need like below code.
4. once this is achieved, remaining I will handle from my end.

   ```
   <div id="form-component" data-endpoint-12345="details.12345.json" data-endpoint-67890="details.67890.json">...</div>
   ```

```js
$('.form-component').attr({"data-endpoint-12345": 'details.12345.json', "data-endpoint-67890": 'details.67890.json'});
```

```html
HTML Dropdown to read data-endpoint FOR Loop:

<div class="apply-container">
   <h3>Choose Date</h3>
   <div class="dropdown date">
      <button id="startDate" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-outline-dark dropdown-toggle detail-apply">14 Oct 2021</button> 
      <div aria-labelledby="startDate" class="dropdown-menu selectdate">
        <a type="button" data-key="12345" data-endpoint-12345="details.12345.json" class="dropdown-item">14 Oct 2021</a>
        <a type="button" data-key="67890" data-endpoint-67890="details.67890.json" class="dropdown-item">24 Oct 2022</a>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

   <!-- Embed format after JS script works - example: <div id="form-component" data-endpoint-12345="details.12345.json" data-endpoint-67890="details.67890.json">...</div> -->
<div class="form-component">...</div>
```

Comment: Please elaborate more .

Comment: @Swati Thanks for your response and help. Updated my requirement. Need to get each dropdown-menu <a> data-endpoint and embed in DIV ID like format required in DOM. remaining logic i will handle which is ready already. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first get data-key attribute value and then using this value get data-endpoint value and then add this to your `form-component` div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".selectdate a").each(function() {
  var key = $(this).data("key"); //get key
  var json_file = $(this).data("endpoint-" + key) //get key endpoint..
  $("#form-component").attr("data-endpoint-" + key, json_file) //add them
  console.log("data-endpoint-" + key + "," + json_file)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="apply-container">
  <h3>Choose Date</h3>
  <div class="dropdown date">
    <button id="startDate" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" class="btn btn-outline-dark dropdown-toggle detail-apply">14 Oct 2021</button>
    <div aria-labelledby="startDate" class="dropdown-menu selectdate">
      <a type="button" data-key="12345" data-endpoint-12345="details.12345.json" class="dropdown-item">14 Oct 2021</a>
      <a type="button" data-key="67890" data-endpoint-67890="details.67890.json" class="dropdown-item">24 Oct 2022</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="form-component">...</div>
```